# SharePoint 2013: JavaScript Object Model - Caml Query where list item is selected

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, caml-query, client-object-model

How could I use a caml query to only get the list items that are selected using the JavaScript Object Model?

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name= ??? />
     <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

For example, a user can select one, many, or all items in a list. I have a list on a page and I want to get the item(s) that are selected and do something with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not use a CAML query to do that.  You can get the selected items using [`SP.ListOperations.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff409526%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
```

See [this related answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/98405/8992).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. When I use the above, I get the id of the list item(s) selected. If I need to get the value of the fields in that list item, do I use the id of the items selected in a caml query?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can create a CAML query to get the items with the specified IDs.  Since you are working in JavaScript, this library might help you: https://camljs.codeplex.com .  I have not used it yet, but I will the next time I am using CAML queries in JavaScript.