# how to use javascript for custom ribbon actions

Tags: 2013, custom-actions, app

Im working on a client request where they want a ribbon action, called 'Copy Document Links', to, when clicked, show a modal pop-up with the url's of the selected document items. Which they can easily then copy out from.

So I have [followed a guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142381.aspx) to help place a custom ribbon action, and I am now just wondering how to approach the actual code side of this.

My initial thinking is to, when the button is clicked, use JavaScript to get the ID's of the selected documents in the list, find their URL's, and then show the pop-up ([using this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98404/how-to-get-the-selected-items-of-list-in-the-javascript)).

My main question is, where would I add this code? Somewhere in the CustomAction VS solution? Or in a javascript file on the site itself, which I then reference to?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll find two ways in the question I marked this as a duplicate of. I guess for mainenance reasons it would make sense to reference an external `js`file instead of writing the script "inline" in the action definition itself

Comment: ah thanks, missed that question when looking for similar solutions. :) will look to see if it provides the answers im looking for. Thanks!